# Finding average of the numbers user's type into an array

Tags: c#, arrays, sum, average

Could someone please explain to me why my average keeps coming as 0 when I run my program? I have listed the entire code of my project on here and have literally never used arrays before.  Also, is the name of this array mData? I tried reading in my book to determine what to look for in these items and have come up with nothing.

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
{

    private const int mSize = 20;
    private int[] mData = new int[mSize];
    private int mIndex = 0;


    private static void Main()
    {
        frmMain main = new frmMain();
        Application.Run(main);
    }
    private frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int num;
        num = int.Parse(txtInput.Text);

        //store num in the array
        mData[mIndex] = num;
        mIndex = mIndex + 1;

        //check for full array
        if (mIndex == mSize)
        {
            //inform user that array is full
            MessageBox.Show("The array is full.");
            btnEnter.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }

    private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int n;

        for (n = 0; n < mIndex; n++)
            listBoxOutput.Items.Add(mData[n]);
    }

    private void btnAverage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int sum = 0;
        int average = 0;

        if (mIndex == 0)
        {
            //inform user that array is empty
            MessageBox.Show("The array is empty.");
        }

        //add up the values
        for (int i = 0; i < mData.Length; i++)
        {
            sum += mData[i];
        }

        //divide by the number of values
        average = sum / mSize;

        listBoxOutput.Items.Add("The average of the array is: " + average);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that you are using ints. If the final value is a decimal less than 1, the int average will store 0. Changing average to a float will solve this. Also, you should not divide by mSize unless you know the entire array is filled. The user could insert one value, but it would be averaged with 19 0s.

Comment: You could just divide by mIndex, since it already stores the number of numbers in the array. You could also use mIndex as the limit in the loop where you sum up the numbers, but that part is fine how it is because it is just adding 0s to the sum once it passes the final user-entered number.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't realize the rest of the array was filled with 0's. That helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

since `average`, `sum`, and `mSize` are intergers, when you divide them, the result will be truncated.

```
   average = sum / mSize;
```

so if `sum/mSize` is less than 1, `average` will always be equal to 0

to get average to have decimal points change the declaration to

```
    double average = 0;
```

and the calculation to

```
average = (double)sum / (double)mSize;
```

Answer (score 0):

Array has a built in property to calculate average which returns a decimal value as output. Example is below

int[] integer = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
Console.WriteLine(integer.Average().ToString());

Hope this helps.